# Is there a way to display multiple power point documents in separate power point windows?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

In Microsoft PowerPoint 2007, when opening multiple .pptx/.ppt documents simultaneously, the documents are opened in the same physical PowerPoint window.

I was wondering if anyone was aware of a way to separate these documents into separate physical windows.

I am aware that you can arrange and cascade separate documents within the *same* PowerPoint window, but I find that method a bit awkward and frustrating (especially when juggling more than two documents simultaneously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, no, you cannot run multiple instances of Powerpoint.  But there are workarounds:

http://whiteeagle.wordpress.com/2006/11/05/how-to-have-multiple-instances-of-powerpoint/

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now supported in PowerPoint 2010.  <strike>(Currently in beta)</strike>

Comment: Oh, good.  I look forward to that.  Haven't had a chance to play with 2010 yet...